# Delete data in Elasticache Redis after 2 days

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, redis, amazon-elasticache

I'm using Redis to store json messages, which need to be consumed by other services. I want the data to store in Redis for 2 days and the data need to be deleted after the 2 days.

Is there any approach to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are storing the data in a [String](https://redis.io/commands/?group=string)—which is likely if you're using ElastiCache—you can [SET](https://redis.io/commands/set/) the value and [EXPIRE](https://redis.io/commands/expire/) it in a [single command](https://redis.io/commands/setex/):

```
SETEX foo 172800 value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timeout on key using the `EXPIRE` command. See the [doc](https://redis.io/commands/expire/) for details.